# Brew install nvm. nvm: command not found

Tags: homebrew, nvm

After installing nvm with brew, and running `nvm`, it says `nvm: command not found`

How can I get the command to execute?

Answer (score 187, accepted):

There are two steps to installing nvm with brew.

First use brew to install the application:

`brew install nvm`

Then take a look at the brew info "caveats" section, to see what else you have to do:

`brew info nvm`

You might see something like (this can change!):

```
You should create NVM's working directory if it doesn't exist:

  mkdir ~/.nvm

Add the following to ~/.bash_profile or your desired shell
configuration file:

  export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
  . "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"
```

If you do not have a ~/.bash_profile file, then you can simply create one.

Make sure to **restart your terminal** before trying to run the `nvm` command again.

Comment: You can also run `source ~/.zshrc` or equivalent if you don't want to restart your terminal

Comment: On mac you might have to modify ~/.zprofile instead of ~/.bash_profile

Answer (score 105):

I followed @user3207874's answer, but it still wasn't working for me. I had to run this command after those steps:

```
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
```

Comment: ohh thanks.. it worked.. would you tell me why did it worked but @user3207874's answer did not ?

Comment: why do i have to run it everytime i restart terminal? how to fix it

Answer (score 14):

**please run this command**

> source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh

Comment: in my case zsh did not know the source for nvm shell using this command resolved this

Answer (score 11):

Just adding some explanation for Aaditya's answer to explain why it works. I can't replay because I don't have enough reputation.

Basically there are 2 important steps to follow

Export NVM_DIR location. You need to create this folder if it doesn't exist first.

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
```

Second you need to source nvm's script. It is usually like this

```
. "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"
```

If the path on the second step does work it may be because the path is different in your device. One easy way to find its path is with the command

```
brew --prefix nvm
```

The output will be the path for the nvm installation directory in which the `nvm.sh` file resides. Setting the command inside $() will create a subshell to get that path. We can use it to source the nvm.sh script wherever it is located like this:

```
. $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
```

Using that command is a replacement for `. "/usr/local/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"` in your .bash_profile.

Comment: This answer works for me, thanks you. I add the lines in the "~/.zshrc" file

Answer (score 10):

[From the docs:](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#verify-installation)

> Your system may not have a [.bash_profile file] where the command is
>   set up. Simply create one with touch ~/.bash_profile and run the
>   install script again
>
> you might need to restart your terminal instance. Try opening a new
>   tab/window in your terminal and retry.

Restarting worked for me...Why can't all bugs be so easy?!!

Answer (score 2):

If you use `brew --prefix nvm` you will get your nvm directory path, it may be different to the default in the brew instructions, e.g. `/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm`

You need to replace the path in the .zshrc export statement:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && \. "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"
[ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d" ] && \. "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d"
```

then `source ~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after running `npm install`

The following solution worked for me:

1. Run `brew doctor` to find broken symlinks for NPM
2. Run `brew cleanup` to clean them up

Answer (score 1):

Just adding some new info.
The docs for nvm have this note:

> Homebrew installation is not supported. If you have issues with homebrew-installed nvm, please brew uninstall it, and install it using the instructions below, before filing an issue.

So for anyone coming here, potentially uninstall via brew and install as per recommendation : https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Answer (score 0):

run

> brew reinstall nvm

and then

You should create NVM's working directory if it doesn't exist:
mkdir ~/.nvm

Add the following to your shell profile e.g. ~/.profile or ~/.zshrc:

> export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"   [ -s
> "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && .
> "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm   [ -s
> "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" ] && .
> "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm"  # This
> loads nvm bash_completion