# Terminal not recognizing nvm after installed with home brew

Tags: bash, macos, command-line, terminal, nvm

I installed nvm via homebrew, but when I run nvm -v or nvm --version form terminal I receive the message command not found: nvm. When I look in finder and cmd+shift+. I can see the ~/.nvm folder.

Initially I did not have a .bash_profile in my user directory, so I added one and the command to recognize nvm per this post:
[Brew install nvm. nvm: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53118850/brew-install-nvm-nvm-command-not-found/54012679)

However, that did not resolve the issue. I've not had this issue with an nvm install before, What could be going on here?

I am on macOS Catalina 10.15.6

Answer (score 48):

I was facing the same issue after installing nvm. Whenever my iTerm / terminal restarts, nvm is gone.

Steps I followed to make it work.

After installing it, update the Homebrew package list and install NVM.

```
brew update
brew install nvm
```

Next, create a directory for NVM.

```
mkdir ~/.nvm
```

Now add these lines to ~/.bash_profile ( or ~/.zshrc for macOS Catalina or later)

```
export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
```

Echoing $NVM_DIR should now return your NVM directory

```
:$ echo $NVM_DIR
/Users/username/.nvm
```

Now running `nvm -v` should return nvm’s options.
To see what Node versions are available to install run:

```
nvm ls-remote
```

For me, I just needed the latest point release of Node version 11 so I ran

```
nvm install 11
```

After installing you can verify what is installed with

```
nvm ls
```

If you have multiple versions and you want to specify which version you would like to use, simply use:

```
nvm use 11
```

to use Node version 11.
Switching back to, let’s say, version 12 would be as easy as `nvm use 12.`
After switching to node version 11, all my packages installed properly.

Comment: This was the answer that fixed for me iTerm and oh my zsh not loading nvm after installing and restarting, macOS Big Sur.

Comment: Should restart terminal before using nvm commands.

Comment: results in no such file or directory: /opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh

Answer (score 5):

For my scenario, I was able to fix by uninstalling `nvm` and then reinstalling via `curl`, which seems to have worked.

I also created a `.zshrc` file, which apparently `mac OS 10.15` and up needs.

I used the documentation here to uninstall and reinstall:
https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#about

`.zshrc` requirement:

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#troubleshooting-on-macos

The steps I took:

1. From terminal, run

```
rm -fr "$NVM_DIR"
```

2. Then on the same terminal, run

```
touch ~/.zshrc
```

to create a `.zshrc` file.

3. Now run

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash
```

4. Finally, run

```
~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```